# Python: Return Count of Words in a List of 2000 Texts

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I feel almost certain that I am overlooking something really obvious, and so I ask this question hoping to be embarrassed: I have a `pandas` dataframe with a little over 2000 texts in one column. My original goal was, and remains, to count the words in each text and create a new column in the dataframe with that word count.

In an effort to simplify the problem, I pulled out the column of texts into a list of strings using the following:

```
texts = data.text.tolist()
```

Type is `list` and the `len` of the list is 2113, which is the number of rows in the dataframe. My current effort is:

```
word_counts = []
for text in texts:
    count = len(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", text))
    word_counts.append(count)
```

For which I receive: `TypeError: expected string or buffer`.

If I run an evaluation of an individual text:

```
len(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", texts[0]))
```

I get the expected result: 2176.

What am I not seeing?

**EDIT** to add sample:

```
texts[0].split()[:10]

['Thank', 'you', 'so', 'much', 'Chris.', 'And', 
"it's", 'truly', 'a', 'great']
```

These are transcripts of talks, so some punctuation, and perhaps a few numbers.

Comment: Could you paste some example of your texts here ? Sorry but I am confused about why "TypeError: expected string or buffer" happend

Comment: Do you have any underscores or dashes in your texts? Or does white-space separate each word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to return the `len` of each string, and apply that function to the `pd.Series` containing the strings.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'text': ["This is-four words.", "This is five whole words."]})
data
#   text
# 0 This is-four words.
# 1 This is five whole words.

def count_words(cell):
    try:
        return len(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", cell))
    except AttributeError:
        return cell

data['word_count'] = data['text'].apply(count_words)
data

#   text                        word_count
# 0 This is-four words.         4
# 1 This is five whole words.   5
```

However, if you know that the words in each text are separated only by white-space (i.e., not by underscores or dashes), then I would recommend this method:

```
def count_words2(cell):
    try:
        return len(cell.split())
    except TypeError:
        return cell

count_words3 = lambda x: len(str(x).split())
```

It is much faster than using a regular expression. In Jupyter Notebook:

```
test_str = "test " * 1000
%timeit count_words(test_str)
%timeit count_words2(test_str)
%timeit count_words3(test_str)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 158 µs per loop
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 29.8 µs per loop
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 28.7 µs per loop
```

Comment: I'm looking this over now and trying it out ... in my Jupyter Notebook. (Are you inside my study?)

Comment: I am fairly sure that this is the answer. I'm getting the following error: `--> 210     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    211 
    212 if sys.hexversion >= 0x02020000:

TypeError: expected string or buffer` ... and I'm thinking that I may have some null values for some of the texts that is causing this to hiccup. (Could that be?)

Comment: Are you sure that `string` is actually type `str`? It looks like it's something else. Perhaps a list?

Comment: It might be. Do you have any `NaN` or `None` values?

Comment: On the matter of string: `type(data.text[0])` returns: `str`.

Comment: I'm working on going through the list ... and the `texts[185].split()` returns: `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable`. Gah! Any way to tell the script simply to skip such an entry or give it a zero? (For later calculations, I can simply skip 0s.) Oi. I just realized I'm going to be writing some `if` statements now...

Comment: you could put a `try` `except TypeError` in `count_words()`

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking outloud by the time I got to the `if` business. I'll mark this as the answer. If you're up for adding a way to skip the floats ... or would it be possible simply to force everything in that column to be a string?

Comment: I'm not sure of the syntax on that: `def count_words(cell): \
    try len(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", cell)) \
    except TypeError \
    return` (SO doesn't allow returns in comments, dang it.)

Comment: I would write `return cell` so that you don't change whatever is in the cell

Comment: Ah ... that's something I have yet to get as I teach myself Python. Many, many thanks for your patience. I suspected a function was called for, but I kept thinking the solution was simpler than that. Again, thanks!

Comment: Got it. Edited the exception to: `except AttributeError:` and the script ran. But everything in the word_count column is `NaN`. Eh? Python, some time you are more master/mistress than I can handle.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you don't have to use regex and don't need to output the values to list. You can try using a `lambda` function instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['Hello world', 'Hello, there world', 'Hello']})
         col1
0        Hello world
1  Hello there world
2              Hello
```

Then you can just use a `lambda` function.

```
df['count'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x).split()))
         col1          count
0        Hello world      2
1  Hello there world      3
2              Hello      1
```

Or, if you want to use `regex`, you can still use the `lambda` function:

```
df['count'] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x: len(re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z_]+", x)))
col1          count
    0        Hello world      2
    1  Hello there world      3
    2              Hello      1
```

Comment: This will only work if all the words are separated by white-space. If there is a hyphen between two words, this method will treat that as one word. Not sure that that's what OP wants.

Comment: @Jakub I am not an expert in English grammar but I am fairly sure hyphen connected words, (I think they're called compound adjectives) should be counted as one word, not two. I think the same is true with underscores. In any case, my answer also includes the regex solution in the lambda function as well.